# How do i center a container horizontal and vertical inside another container?

Tags: html, css

I am messing around in html, and i want this article to be horizontal and vertical in the center of the section. I have looked at different forums online, and none are working. Here is the code.

```css
/* Style */

    #section {
     width: 70%;
     height: 800px;
     background: #555;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-top: 50px;
     margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
    
    #nav {
     height: 100px;
    }
    
    #article {
     width: 90%;
     height: 400px;
     background-color: #fff;
    }
    
    #footer {
     width: 100%;
     height: 200px;
     background-color: #fff;
    }

/* Nav */
    
    body {
      font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      padding: 20px 50px 150px;
      font-size: 13px;
      text-align: center;
      background: #E3CAA1;
    }
    
    ul {
      text-align: left;
      display: inline;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
      list-style: none;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    }
    ul li {
      font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: -4px;
      position: relative;
      padding: 15px 20px;
      background: #fff;
      cursor: pointer;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
      -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
      -o-transition: all 0.2s;
      transition: all 0.2s;
    }
    ul li:hover {
      background: #555;
      color: #fff;
    }
    ul li ul {
      padding: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 48px;
      left: 0;
      width: 150px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: none;
      -moz-box-shadow: none;
      box-shadow: none;
      display: none;
      opacity: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
      -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
      -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
      -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
      -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
      -transition: opacity 0.2s;
    }
    ul li ul li { 
      background: #555; 
      display: block; 
      color: #fff;
      text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
    }
    ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
    ul li:hover ul {
      display: block;
      opacity: 1;
      visibility: visible;
    }


HTML
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/nav.css">
      <title>Alec Grogan | Home</title>
     </head>
     <body>
      <header id="header">
       <h1>Alec Grogan</h1>
      </header>
      <nav id="nav">
       <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Resume</li>
        <li>Portfolio
         <ul>
          <li>Web Design</li>
          <li>Photoshop</li>
         </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
      <section id="section">
       <article id="article">
       </article>
      </section>
      <footer id="footer">
      </footer>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center horizontal and vertical use the following:

Parent container add this to the style :

> position: relative;

The container you want to center add this to the style:

> margin: auto; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right:
>   0;

result is the following:

```css
#section {
    width: 70%;
    height: 800px;
    background: #555;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
#nav {
    height: 100px;
}
#article {
    width: 90%;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
body {
    font-family:'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 20px 50px 150px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #E3CAA1;
}
ul {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
ul li {
    font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    background: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
ul li:hover {
    background: #555;
    color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul li ul li {
    background: #555;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover {
    background: #666;
}
ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
     <h1>Alec Grogan</h1>

</header>
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Resume</li>
        <li>Portfolio
            <ul>
                <li>Web Design</li>
                <li>Photoshop</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<section id="section">
    <article id="article"></article>
</section>
<footer id="footer"></footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually really simple, all you got to do is add to your **#article** the following code:

```
float: right;
```

To know more about floats you can take a look at this website http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp and know more about this element!

Answer (score 0):

try to update your css with the below to achieve!!

The CSS:

```
article{
display:table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```